# Infinite Scroll with Isotope and filtering in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, jquery-isotope

I have searched just about every forum out there and found several ways to make a Isotope masonry layout with filtering work with Infinite Scroll running Wordpress. And none of them seem to be giving me what I'm looking for.

At the moment I got the Masonry layout working, with filtering. When I implement Infinite Scroll it loads the content underneath the other content, a pretty common issue working with Isotope and Infinite scroll. However, when applying the [.appended method](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#appended) in order to sort the newly loaded posts into my site, it messes up my whole layout.

I suspect I'm not entering the .appended line at the right place. Here's my js without the `.append`:

```
$(function () {
    var $page = $('#page')
});

$(function () {
    var $container = $('#content'),
            filters = {},
            // get filter from hash, remove leading '#'
            filterSelector = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        // bind isotope to window resize
        $(window).smartresize(function () {
            // jQuery has issues with percentage widths
            // so we'll manually calulate it
            var colW = Math.floor($container.width() * 0.49);

            $container.isotope({
            });
            // trigger resize so isotope layout is triggered
        }).smartresize();
    });

    $('#nav a').click(function () {
        // store filter value in object
        // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
        var $this = $(this),
                name = $this.attr('data-filter-name'),
                value = $this.attr('data-filter-value'),
                isoFilters = [],
                filterName, prop;

        filters[ name ] = value;

        for (prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[ prop ]);
        }

        var filterSelector = isoFilters.join('');

        // trigger isotope if its ready
        if ($container.data('isotope')) {
            $container.isotope({filter: filterSelector});
        }

        window.location.hash = filterSelector;

        // toggle highlight
        $this.parents('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.parent().addClass('selected');

        return false;

    });

    // if there was a filter, trigger a click on the 
    // corresponding option
    if (filterSelector) {
        var selectorClasses = filterSelector.split('.').slice(1);
        $.each(selectorClasses, function (i, selectorClass) {
            $('#nav a[data-filter-value=".' + selectorClass + '"]').click();
        });
    }

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        filter: filterSelector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });
});
```

`#nav` being my menu, `#content` being my container, and `.box` being my posts.

Could anyone advise me as to where I need to insert the `.appended` command?

Comment: The .appended method is not meant to work with sorting and filtering, see documentation; also, the documentation discourages using infinite scroll with filtering and sorting for some good reasons ;)

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#infinite_scroll_with_filtering_or_sorting

Comment: See the authors opinion on combining filtering/sorting with infinite scroll. He also advices to use the insert method instead of the appended method in a case like this. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#infinite_scroll_with_filtering_or_sorting